# How to replace JSON Object Array with a new array

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through the `allData` and search if the `id` matches `12345`,
I want to remove the Offer Object and insert the `newOffer` Object

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newOfferToInsert = {
        "id":   "12345",
        "name": "ssfd Offer"
    }

    var idToSearch = '12345'

    var allData = [{
        "id": {
            "Street": "555 92nd St S",
            "id": "12345"
        },
        "Offer": {
            "id": "12345"
        }
    }, {
        "id": {
            "Street": "666 DFTYY",
            "id": "345"
        },
        "Offer": {
            "id": "345"
        }
    }];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9avwsm1p/

Comment: [There's no such thing as a _"JSON Object Array"_](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). That's an array of objects.

Comment: What is the new offer object that you want to insert?

Comment: `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.splice()`, `for(...)`, ...

Comment: @Terry `var newOfferToInsert = {...`

Comment: I want to insert the newOfferToInsert

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried and where you're having issues.

Comment: To find the object: [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/215552)

Comment: You don't need to remove anything; just set the `Offer` to the new object.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
allData.forEach(function(cartObj) {
    if(cartObj.id.id === idToSearch){   
        cartObj.Offer = newOfferToInsert;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newOfferToInsert = {
  "id": "12345",
  "name": "ssfd Offer"
}

const idToSearch = '12345'

const allData = [{
  "id": {
    "Street": "555 92nd St S",
    "id": "12345"
  },
  "Offer": {
    "id": "12345"
  }
}, {
  "id": {
    "Street": "666 DFTYY",
    "id": "345"
  },
  "Offer": {
    "id": "345"
  }
}];


console.log(replaceOffer(allData, idToSearch, newOfferToInsert))

function replaceOffer(allData, idToSearch, newOfferToInsert) {
  return allData.map(element => {
    if (element.Offer.id === idToSearch) {
      element.Offer = newOfferToInsert
    }
    return element
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var newOfferToInsert = {
    "id":   "12345",
    "name": "ssfd Offer"
}

var idToSearch = '12345'

var allData = [{
    "id": {
        "Street": "555 92nd St S",
        "id": "12345"
    },
    "Offer": {
        "id": "12345"
    }
}, {
    "id": {
        "Street": "666 DFTYY",
        "id": "345"
    },
    "Offer": {
        "id": "345"
    }
}];
```

allData.forEach((obj)=>{

```
if(obj.Offer.id===idToSearch)
{
    obj.Offer=newOfferToInsert

}
```

})

console.log(allData)